# Auto scalling policy for wordfreq application by aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I am pretty new to cloud and I have been trying to improve my skills. I came accross the word freq application which basically returns the top 10 words with highest freq from a document. I am trying to deploy the same application on aws with an auto scaling group but I am not able to decide what performance metrics to use for scaling out or scaling in.
Any help would be great.

I am not sure what performance metrics is good for this task. I tried using sum CPU utilization but I am not sure if that is the right metric to use in this case.

Comment: The best way to determine metrics is to run the application, then monitor the metrics and find the 'bottleneck' (the most constrained resource). Hopefully, your application can multi-thread otherwise it would be wasting CPU resources. Counting words is unlikely to be memory-intensive (it is easy to keep a dictionary of words in memory). If you have _massive_ amounts of input data, then network I/O might be the bottleneck, since it would need to read the data somehow. Nobody can tell you how to configure Auto Scaling -- it all depends on how the application behaves.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein
I tried running the code and monitoring the metrics. It gave me some insights and I will work on that.